# CDAP deployment on GKE 1.22 and later versions

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, cdap

I am not able to deploy CDAP onto the GKE version 1.22 + versions.

Getting error
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "CDAPMaster" in version "apiextensions.k8s.io/v1"

https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/911179793/Installing+CDAP+on+Kubernetes

Does CDAP only support GKE 1.21 version as we had no issues with that.

Comment: If you copied the "cdap-operator.yaml", then it won't work on 1.22 because it still uses the `apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1` API which was removed in 1.22.  Looks like https://github.com/cdapio/cdap-operator/blob/develop/config/crd/bases/cdap.cdap.io_cdapmasters.yaml has been updated.

Comment: Thanks @GariSingh , right it was still using beta1 however even after removing beta1 it failed as it had some other specs which were not compatible. Thanks for sharing the reference, it has the complete crd yaml with all the latest changes.

Answer (score 1):

I could resolve the deployment issue by using the customresourcedefinition which @gari has shared in the comment.
Additionally,  for CDAP deployment i had to use below api in GKE 1.22 version.

apiVersion: cdap.cdap.io/v1alpha1
kind: CDAPMaster

Answer (score 0):

**Error :** INSTALLATION FAILED: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "CDAPMaster" in version "apiextensions.k8s.io/v1" states that your **apiextensions.k8s.io/v1 API version of [CustomResourceDefinition](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/extend-resources/custom-resource-definition-v1/) is no longer supported.**

Please refer to [Removed API versions in 1.22](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/release-notes#removed_api_versions_in_122) for more details.

**CDAP Operator is still under active development and has not been extensively tested in production environments.** Backward compatibility of the APIs is not guaranteed for alpha releases. Beta versions of previously graduated APIs are removed in 1.22 in favor of the GA version : **apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1**, CustomResourceDefinition.

**Steps to be taken to run through the resources that are affected by these removals :**

1. You can use the v1 API to retrieve or update existing objects, even if they were created using an older API version. If you defined any custom resources in your cluster, those are still served after you upgrade.
2. If you're using external CustomResourceDefinitions, you can use [kubectl convert](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/07/14/upcoming-changes-in-kubernetes-1-22/#kubectl-convert) to translate existing manifests to use the newer API. Because there are some functional differences between beta and stable CustomResourceDefinitions, our advice is to test out each one to make sure it works how you expect after the upgrade.

Also go through the official blog post [Kubernetes API and Feature Removals In 1.22](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/07/14/upcoming-changes-in-kubernetes-1-22/#api-changes) for
more information.

Comment: Thanks @Veera for this info, yes i have modified the CRD  and cdap-spec to make it work with latest kube versions. Also i posted the answer with exact changes.